# CMMotionActivityManager suddenly not recognizing motion correct anymore

Tags: swift, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I'm using the CMMotionActivityManager to get updates of motions. This tracking worked fine until later today when the motion sensor started recognizing walking as cycling. I've changed nothing in my code and the code is simple:

```
if let m = motion, m.confidence == .high || m.confidence == .medium {
    print("NEW MOTION \(m)")
}
```

Is there any way to reset the manager or had somebody else the same issue?

Comment: What does the Health app say? It records motion all the time.

Comment: How can I check there for cycling specific in the Health app? @matt

Answer (score 0):

So as it seems, the Motion Sensor of iPhones tends to just not work properly from time to time.

To fix this issue, you have to follow these complicated steps:

1. Restart your Phone
2. Profit.